# How to troublshoot slower OS X performance

Tags: macos, performance

I have a Mac running OS X 10.8.4 with 4 GB RAM. But, for some days it seems bit slower in performance. If I switched on the system and logged into my user account and if I monitor the performance via `active monitor` it shows above 90% CPU is idle almost all the time.

But when I open the terminal as the first application, it will open instantly, but it take 5–10 seconds to get ready. Means, it will take that time (5–10 seconds) to enable me to type anything in that terminal.

When I open Google Chrome, it will stay loading with a blank white page for a while. I have created another user account for me in OS X, but still it shows the same slower performance.

Now please advice me, how to troubleshoot this issue. I have no idea what could be the problem with my machine, since it is slow right after booting (before running any applications).

Comment: Use Activity Monitor to find out what processes are using the CPU. Alternatively type `ps -aux` in the terminal to list the running processes. That will help you / us diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to run a hardware diagnostic.  Assuming this is a mac, run the [Apple Hardware Test](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509).  If it's not a mac, you could test components individually.  Run memtest86 or an on-board memory diagnostic to verify functionality, and most importantly, run a hard drive diagnostic.  Seatools for dos is a fantastic utility, but you can use other manufacturer's tools per hard drive.

Second, you need to run a virus scan.  I have personally never seen a virus on a mac, but I have heard of them.  You could try running a virus scan with [Webroot](http://www.webroot.com/us/en/), which has a free 30-day trial.

At this point, you can be fairly confident that your hardware is in good working condition and your computer is free of malware.  A common cause of slowness in computers is failing hardware and/or malware.

Next install all system updates (apple updates).  Ensure you have the latest software and patches.  Clean up any old, unneeded files, wipe browser cache and cookies, uninstall old unused programs, and generally free up available disk space wherever possible (and safe to do so).  I would also run the Apple Disk Utility to verify permissions.

If the computer is still very slow at this point, it may be in need of more advanced operating system repair.  Reloading the operating system might be your best bet unless you can find someone who knows a lot about mac operating systems.